# Tensorflow ExhuastedResourceError

Tags: python, error-handling, tensorflow, out-of-memory

I have searched that the error was solve for some people by reducing the batch size (e.g. to 128). I still get the same error and my batch size is only 10. But the input to my CNN is a 1x500 spectrogram. When I use a 1x200 spectrogram there's no error.